# Get id_token from Google API OAuth using username, password, client_id - without client_secret

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I need to programatically get **id_token** from Google OAuth2.
The only input I have is username, password and client_id for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no API to do that. I may be able to help if you describe what you are trying to do. A non Google app should not be collecting Google password from a user.